# Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a select change its name whenever I select a certain option, but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong here?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var line = 1;

    $("#code").append("<span id='condition" + line + "'>when<select name='project starts' id='selection" + line + "'><option value='project starts'>project starts</option><option value='is clicked'>is clicked</option><option value='is unclicked'>is unclicked</option><option value='is created'>is created</option></select>&nbsp;<button class='delete-btn' id=" + line + ">-</button><br></span>");
    line++;

    $("select").on("change", function() {
      $("#" + this.id).attr("name", $("#" + this.id + "option:selected").val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML with the select element

Comment: Your selector is `#selection1option:selected` - see the problem? That aside, `$("#"+this.id)` is a redundant way of writing `$(this)`, and `$("#"+this.id+" option:selected").val()` is better off as just `this.value`. Seriously all you need is `this.name = this.value;` -- although why you'd do that is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

this code is only for your reference

```
<input id="country_name" type="text" value="Land: Deutschland" class="noinput country_name" readonly="">
```

```
var drop_value = document.getElementById('country_name');
    $('#dropdown_country').on('change', function() {
    drop_value.setAttribute("value", 'Land: '+this.value);
  });
```